# Can't get my PHP to show error when form field is blank

Tags: php, forms

I am making a PHP Journal through a form, but no matter what I do, it always comes up as successfully posted. I've tried using empty() and null but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the HTML for the form:

```
<form action="journal_post.php" method="post">
    <p>Give your entry a title.</p>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="title" />
    <p>What is your mood today?</p>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="mood" />
    <p>Now please tell me about your day.</p>
    <textarea class="input" name="entry" rows="12" cols="75" type="text"> </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="submit" type="image" src="submit.png" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
<form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "blahblah";
debug_to_console($password);
//Establishing Connection with Server
$connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

//Selecting Database from Server
$journal_db = mysql_select_db("journal_db", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $mood = $_POST['mood'];
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];
    if($title !=''||$entry !=''){
        //Insert Query of SQL
        $query = mysql_query("insert into entrys(j_title, j_mood, j_entry) values ( '$title', '$mood', '$entry')");

        echo "<br/><br/><span>Journal entry recorded..!!</span>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
    }
}
//Closing Connection with Server
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if($title !=''||$entry !=''){
```

to:

```
if($title !=''&&$entry !=''){
```

You want to check that **both** `$title` **and** `$entry` aren't empty, **not** either-or.

Comment: @MichelleNetto Does this answer help? If it does, then please accept. If not, feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use isset() to check the field before insertion into database

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
<textarea class="input" name="entry" rows="12" cols="75" type="text"> </textarea>
```

actually adds a space in the entry, change it to

```
<textarea class="input" name="entry" rows="12" cols="75" type="text"></textarea>
```